# Clone Power BI reports between tenants using Power BI REST API

Tags: powerbi, multi-tenant, powerbi-rest-api

I have 2 workspaces:

- Workspace A hosted on tenant A: Vendor workspace which contains the product PBIX. "Golden workspace".
- Workspace B: Client workspace, hosted on tenants B, client workspace.

On workspace A I have :
Dataset + report
A Report which is connected to the dataset above.

I want to copy the content workspace A to workspace B using the rest API.
(I am using python).

**I am using PPU or Pro license, I don't have premium capacity.**

I want to copy the content workspace A to workspace B using the rest API.
(I am using python).
I am pretty familiar with Power BI service principal profiles and used them several times.

a legit solution can be to import PBIX files to workspace B, I don't must to clone workspace A.

[My final goal is to create a workflow like the one on this line @23:14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1vVFoKKrwE)

Thank you, Tal

Comment: This workflow assumes one single tenant. In case of two different tenants, your only option is to export from tenant A, save locally, and re-publish to tenant B.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov if that's the case, how we can update the database to "Tenant B" before the upload? Dataset Name should be changed before upload in order the respective dataset to be created. This should be done programmatically.

Comment: @StavrosKoureas You can't change anything before upload. All the changes are made after uploading, using the API.